# How to find the intersection of the tangent plane with x- / y-axis

Tags: calculus

Having an equation of the tangent plane like:

$2x+4y-z-5 = 0$

How do I calculate the intercept with the y-axis and the intercept with the x-axis?

Is it enough to set $x=0$ and $z=0$ if I want to find the intercept with the y-axis?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, that works

Comment: $ 4y -5 = 0 $ is plane perpedicular to $ Oy. $